# Count Boolean values from Pivot table with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean, pivot-table

I have a dataframe `df` defined like so:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   a   z   l   1   qqq True
1   a   z   l   2   qqq True
2   a   z   l   3   qqq False
3   a   z   r   1   www True
4   a   z   r   2   www False
5   a   z   r   2   www False
6   s   x   7   2   eee True
7   s   x   7   3   eee False
8   s   x   7   4   eee True
9   s   x   5   1   eee True
10  d   c   l   1   rrr True
11  d   c   l   2   rrr False
12  d   c   r   1   fff False
13  d   c   r   2   fff True
14  d   c   r   3   fff True
```

My goal is to create a table based on the unique values of columns `A`, `B` and `C` so that I am able to count the number of elements of column `D` and the unique number of elements in column `C`.

The output looks like this:

```
       D    E
A   B       
a   z   6   2
d   c   5   2
s   x   4   2
```

Where for example the 6 is how many elements are present in the column `A` having value `a`, and 2 indicates the number of unique elements in column `E` (`qqq`,`wwww`).

I was able to achgieve this goal by using the following lines of code:

```
# Define dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','a','a','a','a','s','s','s','s','d','d','d','d','d'],
                   'B':   ['z','z','z','z','z','z','x','x','x','x','c','c','c','c','c'],
                   'C':  ['l','l','l','r','r','r','7','7','7','5','l','l','r','r','r'],
                   'D':    ['1','2','3','1','2','2','2','3','4','1','1','2','1','2','3'],
                   'E':    ['qqq','qqq','qqq','www','www','www','eee','eee','eee','eee','rrr','rrr','fff','fff','fff'],
                   'F':   [True,True,False,True,False,False,True,False,True,True,True,False,False,True,True]})

# My code so far
a = df.pivot_table(index=['A','B','C'], aggfunc={'E':'nunique', 'D':'count'}).sort_values(by='E')
a = a.pivot_table(index=['A','B'], aggfunc='sum').sort_values(by='E')
```

**The Problem**:

Now I would like also to count the number of `True` or `False` values present in the dataframe with the same criteria presented before so that the result looks like this:

```
        D   E   True    False
A   B               
a   z   6   2      3        3
d   c   5   2      3        2
s   x   4   2      3        1
```

As you can see the number of `True` values where `A`=`a` are 3 and `False` values are 3 as well.

What is a smart and elegant way to achieve my final goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your code, you could extend like this:

```
# My code so far
a = df.pivot_table(index=['A','B','C'], aggfunc={'E':'nunique', 'D':'count','F':sum}).sort_values(by='E').rename(columns={'F':'F_True'})
a = a.pivot_table(index=['A','B'], aggfunc='sum').sort_values(by='E').eval('F_False = D - F_True')
```

OUtput:

```
     D  E  F_True  F_False
A B                       
a z  6  2     3.0      3.0
d c  5  2     3.0      2.0
s x  4  2     3.0      1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need two steps

```
pd.concat([df.groupby(['A','B','C']).agg({'E': 'nunique', 'D':'size'}).sum(level=[0,1])
,df.groupby(['A','B']).F.value_counts().unstack()],1)
Out[702]: 
     E  D  False  True
A B                   
a z  2  6      3     3
d c  2  5      2     3
s x  2  4      1     3
```

Using `value_counts`

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).F.value_counts().unstack()
```